# How to reduce LED flash rate (frequency)

Tags: led, led-driver

I have purchased an LED flasher circuit from Ebay (see jpg) for use on a model plane, but the flash rate on the circuit is much too fast, about 4 flashes a second. I am trying to achieve 1 or 2 flashes a second. What component would I need to change to reduce the flash rate? I have listed the components in the PDF and have drawn out the circuit, so I hope that helps. Many thanks

[image]

Comment: You should post this question to the eBay seller.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer application support.

Answer (score 11):

The fact that there's multiple operating modes indicates that HH5K1 is not in fact a simple device, but most probably a cheap microcontroller¹ or dedicated ASIC that does the blinking. 
I'm afraid that means you *can't* swap anything to do what you want.

So, build a flasher from scratch that does what you want. I rarely do that, but here, using a NE555 might be the simplest thing to do; there's plenty of online circuit example that you can refer to, but frankly, the application examples in the datasheet(s) do contain *astable multivibrators*. Add a smallish capacitor and an BJT to the output – and tadah!, you've got a flasher.

Another option is going the same route as the manufacturer of the board you're looking at: Get some logic to do your work; a [0.30€ attiny](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/attiny4-tshr/microchip-technology?utm_campaign=octopart_2018&utm_currency=EUR&utm_keyword=ATTINY4-TSHR&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_content=inv_listing&utm_source=octopart) would absolutely do the job.

---

¹ The 51 in the name might hint it's a 8051 core clone, but that's not going to help anyone – that thing, if programmable, is very likely only programmable once.

Comment: Thank you, Marcus for your super fast reply. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words – I'd accept an upvote, then!

Comment: Its the least I can do. Up voted.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, here's the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFYchK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could desolder the HH5K1 and put a [PIC10F200](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001239F.pdf) in its place (after programming it, of course).

- Pin 2 would connect to BAT-
- Pin 6 would connect to BAT+
- Pin 4 would connect to R2 and the MOSFETs

You'd just need to add a wire between pins 5 (Vdd) and 6 to power the chip.

Comment: Thank you Dave. That sounds like a good suggestion. I have never tried programming PIC's so it all a bit new to me. I will have to investigate this option.

Comment: If you want to learn to program PICs, this is a great first project. If you don't it will seem like a lot of fuss.